# Exit Puppet when Hiera backend is not found

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am using masterless Puppet. And My situation is that I am using a custom Hiera backend called `hiera-regex`. The process of using it is that you have to have `hiera-regex` installed on your target machine.

If sometime for some reason, `hiera-regex` is not installed, hiera still looks up for the key in hierarchy and starts using that key which it was not suppose to use in the presence of `hiera-regex`. Ideally, I would want Puppet to exit when it does not find `hiera-regex` backend installed. But as of now, Puppet only prints a notice() which can be easily missed and can leave your node in an unwanted state.

Is it possible to somehow configure Puppet/hiera for masterless setup to not continue at all if the backend hiera is configured to use is not installed?

Here is my hiera.yaml file:

```
---
:backends:
    - regex  # this is the custom backend (hiera-regex)
    - yaml

:regex:
    :datadir: /etc/puppet/hiera

:yaml:
    :datadir: /etc/puppet/hiera

:hierarchy:
    - "%{fqdn}"
    - base
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `yaml` from the list of backends?

Comment: Well the issue is that I don't want to remove yaml from the list of backends. How this works is I want to do lookup according regex pattern on FQDN. If that is not found or there is no match, I want to fallback to YAML that has the defaults. And this works just fine. But on a new machine, I might not have the regex backend installed which i can take care of by some automation. But I still want Puppet to fail if the defined backend is not found at all. As of now Puppet only notifies but not fails.